# How can I create triggers in VoltDB using the C# client?

Tags: c#, voltdb

How can I create triggers within a stored procedure in VoltDB?

I am  using the C# VoltDB client. Is the callback in `voltdb.procedures.wrap()` the same as creating triggers?

Answer (score 1):

VoltDB doesn't support traditional triggers, however a stored procedure can contain multiple SQL statements and logic that allow transactions to go through if certain conditions are met. The callback in `voltdb.procedures.wrap()` is where you can code what happens after a response. It can work as a sort of 'trigger' for all intents and purposes.

Full disclosure: I work at VoltDB.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Could you please give an example or any link about multiple SQL statements like a scenario , for every 10 rows in a table , need to insert "some text" into another table.

Comment: Take a look at Designing Stored Procedures (https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/DesignProc.php) for how to write a procedure. This example inserts, selects, and sometimes does more inserts: https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/blob/master/examples/bank-offers/procedures/bankoffers/CheckForOffers.java

Comment: For "every 10 rows" you would just want to be careful to ensure the procedure is deterministic. This could be done using VoltProcedure.getSeededRandomNumberGenerator() https://docs.voltdb.com/javadoc/procedure-api/org/voltdb/VoltProcedure.html#getSeededRandomNumberGenerator-- or you could use getUniqueId https://docs.voltdb.com/javadoc/procedure-api/org/voltdb/VoltProcedure.html#getUniqueId-- and a mod function to do something approximately every 10 times deterministically.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew again.As I mentioned earlier, I am using C# VoltDB client and I could not find statements like public final SQLStmt insertActivity = new SQLStmt("INSERT INTO XXXX VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?);") But I am able to insert, update , upsert and delete using voltDB.Procedures.Wrap<> and Select.Execute().

About the Scenario , I am inserting into table X and whenever the count reached 10 records (10,20,30,....etc) I need to trigger an insert into table Y. Could you please help me to sort out this.